# Having issues with ng-model on select tag, but nowhere else

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a bunch of ng-model statements, they all are working EXCEPT for the one on the select tag. Essentially, picture a page with a list of devices, when one gets clicked, this function runs:

```
/* Opens the unit popup page for TX units */
this.openTxUnitPopup = function (row) {
    var txUnitForPopup = myScope.txUnits.find(function (unit) {
        return unit.mac == row.entity.mac;
    });

    $scope.config.txUnitForPopup = txUnitForPopup.clone();
    $scope.config.showTxPopup = true;
};
```

That function is designed to set up some data for a modal dialog. The markup with the ng-model statements are below. Again, when the modal pop-up appears, everything is filled out properly based on the model EXCEPT the select box. No channel is selected. I can confirm in the debugger that the channel is being changed by the select box, if I pick a channel and then look at the `txUnitForPopup.channel` it has changed. However, in the view, the select box is never pre-filled with a selected option out like the other form elements are when modal first appears..

```
                <div class="form-column">
                    <span class="info-label">Part:</span>
                    <div class="my-form-control">{{config.txUnitForPopup.part}}</div>

                    <span class="info-label">MAC:</span>
                    <div class="my-form-control">{{config.txUnitForPopup.mac}}</div>

                    <span class="info-label">Channel:</span>
                    <select class="my-form-control" ng-model="config.txUnitForPopup.channel">
                        <option
                                ng-repeat="unit in myScope.txUnits"
                                value="{{unit.channel}}">{{unit.channel}}
                        </option>
                    </select>

                    <span class="info-label">Name:</span>
                    <input class="my-form-control" ng-model="config.txUnitForPopup.info.name">

                    <span class="info-label">Manufacturer:</span>
                    <input class="my-form-control" ng-model="config.txUnitForPopup.info.manufacturer">

                    <span class="info-label">Model:</span>
                    <input class="my-form-control" ng-model="config.txUnitForPopup.info.model">

                    <span class="info-label">Serial #:</span>
                    <input class="my-form-control" ng-model="config.txUnitForPopup.info.serial">
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ng-selected to set previously selected value to dropdown list like this

```
                 <select class="my-form-control" ng-model="config.txUnitForPopup.channel">
                        <option
                                ng-repeat="unit in myScope.txUnits"
                                ng-selected="unit.channel == config.txUnitForPopup.channel"
                                value="{{unit.channel}}">{{unit.channel}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the `ng-options` directive in the select rather than the `ng-repeat`.

For example:

`<select ng-options="unit in myScope.txUnits" 
         ng-model="config.txUnitForPopup.channel">
</select>`

Comment: Bizarrely, this does not work at all. If I try it, the options are even available, just an empty list... leading me to wonder if I somehow broke angular on select tags. Not sure how I could have though.

Answer (score 0):

please take another look at ng-options. here goes a plunkr from [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) (with small modifications)

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('defaultValueSelect', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
     availableOptions: [
       {id: '1', name: 'Option A'},
       {id: '2', name: 'Option B'},
       {id: '3', name: 'Option C'}
     ],
     selectedOption: {id: '3', name: 'Option C'} //This sets the default value of the select in the ui
     };
 }]);
})(window.angular);

/*
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
*/
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-select-with-default-values-production</title>
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="defaultValueSelect">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="mySelect">Make a choice:</label>
    <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
      ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id"
      ng-model="data.selectedOption"></select>
  </form>  
  <button ng-click="data.selectedOption = data.availableOptions[1]">
    Set option B</button>
 
  <hr>
  <tt>option = {{data.selectedOption}}</tt><br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<!-- 
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
-->
```